# What's the difference between static method inside a class and a function outside of it (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, function, class, methods, static-methods

I don't really catch what is the purpose of putting a static method into a class and then calling it with this class instead of just creating a function with the same code.

```
class test {
    static sum(a,b){
        return (a+b)
    }
}
sum = (a,b) => a+b
console.log(sum(10,5)) //15
console.log(test.sum(10,5)) //15
```

What is the difference? And why do people use static classes?

Comment: If not too overwhelming, always consider to look at some documentation beforehand https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Comment: Do you understand why classes are needed or used? If not, then you should learn about classes first before thinking about the static methods.

Comment: It is a matter of grouping things together that belong together. Static methods will provide functionality that relates to that class.

Comment: No difference really. Putting static things on a class only ever makes sense if you already *have* a class for some other purpose, and the function somehow belongs to it. Once you import the class, you get the function with it (instead of having to import it separately), purely as a convenience. (Also, in some class inheritance patterns it can be useful to override static methods, but that's rare).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's indeed no real technical difference between a standalone function and a static method on a class. You should not unnecessarily wrap your functions in a class, if there's no difference.

However, it can be advantageous for comprehensibility. For example, the builtin `Date` class has a few static methods, like [`Date.now`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now). This clearly makes sense to have on the `Date` class, since it's very `Date` related. If it wasn't a static method on `Date`, it'd be a global function, which would need to be named something useful and which shouldn't clash with other global names. Just naming it `now` would probably take up a valuable global name and lead to confusion or clashes. Compare:

```
let foo = now();
let bar = Date.now();
```

`Date.now` is much clearer here and also doesn't take up another global name.

---

Now (pun intended), ES6 modules somewhat solve this problem, as it gives you another tool to group related functionality: modules. With modules, you *can* simply export a standalone function *and* a separate class from your module, and the caller can use it as they please:

```
import { now, Date } from 'hypothetical-date';

let foo = now();
let bar = new Date;

// or

import hdate from 'hypothetical-date';

let foo = hdate.now();
let bar = new hdate.Date;
```